# Log full request body with SpringBoot built-in logging service

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, logging

I have a Java Springboot application and want to log the HTTP request body. I managed to do it by setting the field `logging.level.org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor = DEBUG` in my `application.properties`. This create a nice log like that when I get a request:

```
2020-04-27T10:12:46,041 DEBUG 40422 --- [-nio-443-exec-2] RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor  : Read "application/json;charset=UTF-8" to ["{
    "cpName":"SSA, Test 1",
    "contractId":"1234567",
    "contractName":"SSA, Contract 1",
    "scnName":" (truncated)...]
```

However, only the beginning of the body is shown. I don't have the value for the field `scnName` and there is another field after this one called `description` that does not appears either. I search but could not find a way to write the whole body in the log. Is there any settings to change to print everything?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please go through : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-http-logging

Comment: @R.G I don't see anything related to this problem in this page. Did I miss something?

Comment: Sorry for that ,  setting log level for RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor didn’t look like the correct way to log request body , hence the link . I do not have a solution for the log message getting trimmed

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Set the logging level to TRACE:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor=TRACE
```

Source: [SPR-17254 (#21787)](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/21787)

> The logging of encoded and decoded values, for both Spring MVC and
> WebFlux, now logs the full value at TRACE, and up to 100 chars at
> DEBUG. ...